# Encryption Web.config sections

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

I have read about aspnet_regiis for encrypting web.config sections in an ASP.net project, but I am confused how this works since the decryption key must live in plaintext on the actual server somewhere.

I would ideally like to use AES for encryption, but this requires adding the aes key to the web.config in plaintext itself, which seems useless to me. (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777147)

Perhaps I am missing something.. can someone explain how this encryption process is actually secure?

Comment: Secure from whom?  Users outside of the web server should _not_ be able to see the Web.config.  Ever.  If they can, that's a security hole that needs to be plugged.  Or are you talking about people who do have access to the web server?

Comment: "the decryption key must live in plaintext on the actual server somewhere" is an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspnet_regiis encryption is easy to decrypt if you are able to login to a session on the machine and have access to the key.

This protects against a scenario where someone can view the file but cannot login to the machine and a scenario where the decryption key is correctly ACL'ed to a known set of users.

Under the hood it uses DPAPI and machine context specific information. I believe you can also encrypt using a user profile in which case no other user can decrypt it.

Here are some useful links:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/07/29/421063.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must create a key first and than use this key in your web.config

An detailed explanation can be found here: [msdn microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx)

the one under web farm scenario's is the most practical.

I think it's useful to encrypt them if you have a lot of passwords etc. in the web.config.